# Why does a literal value work, but this function in `_.reduce`?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I was trying to do something like as follows:

```
const partitionSize = 3;
_(Orders.findOne(orderId).products)
  .map((product) => Products.findOne(product._id))
  .reduce(function (partitions, product) {
    _.first(_.sortBy(partitions, (p) => p.size)).push(product);
    return partitions;
  }, _.fill(_.range(partitionSize), []))
```

This does not work. It continually pushes to both arrays. However, when I do the following, it does not have the same problem

```
.reduce(function (partitions, product) {
   _.first(_.sortBy(partitions, (p) => p.size)).push(product);
  return partitions;
}, [[], [], []]);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: shouldn't the sortBy line look like: `_.sortBy(partitions, 'length')`?

Comment: Can you post the intended output? It looks like there's probably an easier way of doing what you want.